# Declare a default export for instance of a class

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I am adding TypeScript definitions to an existing package in the form of a separate typings file. The package declares and exports a class by name, but it also exports by default an instance of said class which can be used globally.

I've written the following code (based on this [change](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Breaking-Changes#arbitrary-expressions-are-forbidden-in-export-assignments-in-ambient-contexts) I found) which seems to work, however the syntax used to export the default instance of the class looks too verbose to me. My question is, can this code be improved?

```
export class Example<T> {
  // Implementation removed for brevity.
}

const _default: Example<any>;
export default _default;
```

Comment: Your code does not export the class at the default export.

Comment: No. Your code looks fine expect you should be using the `declare` keyword since you creating types for an existing implementation

Comment: It's not really worth posting answer just to say that no, the code cannot be improved. The documentation that you yourself linked explains it

Comment: @AluanHaddad Thanks for the response. Just to understand, why would the declare statement be needed? Do I need to add this even in a typings file? I am editing the library itself instead of adding the types in my own application.

Comment: Use the declare statement when the types are separated from them implementation.

Answer (score -1):

```
export class Example<T> {
  // Implementation removed for brevity.
}

export default Example;
```

Id remove the const declaration that you probably ment, and simply export it with a second statement. This also preserves the Generic of the class.